# Rails parse JSON params with leading zeroes in POST body

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, post, parameters, eval

I'm writing an API that should receive a POST with JSON in it's body. It already works but when the numbers in the JSON have leading zeroes it gives me this error:

```
eval error: Error occurred while parsing request parameters
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:96:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:92:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:390:in `block in POST'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:389:in `POST'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
  /home/danniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:1232:in `params'
  (rdbg)//home/danniel/workspace/check-my-cep/app/controllers/api/customers_controller.rb:1:in `create'
```

Here's a request that works:
`curl -d '[{"zip": 1001000,"name": "JOSE"}, {"zip": 1001900,"name": "FRANCISCO"}]' http://localhost:3000/api/customers --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

This one doesn't:
`curl -d '[{"zip": 01001000,"name": "JOSE"}, {"zip": 01001900,"name": "FRANCISCO"}]' http://localhost:3000/api/customers --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

The only difference is the leading zeroes in "zip".

My controller is quite simple:

```
class Api::CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: %i[ destroy ]

  def create
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
  end

  private
    def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def customer_params
      params.permit(_json: [:cep, :name]).require(:_json)
    end
end
```

Update: I can't control the request.

Comment: is it a number or a string? If it is a number (which you imply by not having quotes around it) then putting a zero in front of it will cause an error. If it is a string then it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: @Beartech it's a number and that's precisely my issue. I can't change the request and I have to parse it somehow.

Comment: My point is numbers don't have leading zeros. So do you expect to store it as a number or a string?

Comment: JSON does not consider anything with a leading zero a number. Non-numbers must be quoted. Since it is coming in non-quoted then Rails thinks you are trying to parse valid JSON, which it is not.

Comment: When you declare `Content-Type: application/json` you cause the middleware to expect correctly formed JSON. Can you change the content type? Other than that you are looking at hacking your middleware to accept your custom version of JSON.

Comment: @Beartech I store it as a string. It's supposed to be a zip code, so it makes sense to be a string starting with a zero character, but whoever built the JSON that is being sent in the request typed it without the quotes and I don't have any kind of control over those requests, to change content-type or fix the quoting.

Comment: Well it has too many characters to be a zip code. And like I said, at this point you are gong to have to come up with a custom way to handle it since you say you can't affect the request. That means overriding something in the middleware that handles the content coming in.

Comment: @Beartech The zip codes in my country are 8 digit long, that's why. And you are right, I'm currently trying to patch the middleware so this works. Thanks a lot.